# How can i store partitioned data into separate files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

have an input file which contains below text:

```
India’s football team captain Sunil Chhetri recently took to Twitter pleading fans to support his team in a four-nation tournament held in Mumbai. Virat Kohli, the captain of national cricket team, doesn’t have to issue such appeals as he mostly plays in front of a full house.
```

I need to create individual RDD's for individual lines

RDD1 should be my first line
RDD2 should be my second line

my expectation is that create individual RDD's for the separate lines

Could any one please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Would you like to have RDD[RDD[Sring]]?

Comment: No it should be like RDD[First Line]

Comment: As far as I understand, you can use rdd.take(1) for getting the only first-line. For second-line, you can use the following construction: rdd.take(2).drop(1)

Comment: .foreachPartition?